# HTTP request should return a string

Tags: android, http, request

Edit: "hello" has been deleted. So, hello.

By reaching an URL, I should get a string as response. So I borrowed a part of code on this website and adapted in a method to get my string into a variable. Unfortunatelly, the "Try" block is skipped and the returned string is "***". What do I have misunderstood something about this script ?

Is the variable "response" what I should get as a response, or something else ?

Thanks in advance.

```
    private String getMessages() {
    String response = "***";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String getURL = "http://***.com/message/";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
        if (resEntityGet != null) {  
            // do something with the response
            response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
            Log.i("GET RESPONSE", response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: `resEntityGet` must be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this works correctly but this is the basic idea what you must do

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
String response = builder.toString();
```

**UPDATE:**

This is a short snipped of my code, which is working without problems:

```
int statusCode = mResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    InputStream is = null;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                        HttpEntity entity = mResponse.getEntity();
                        if (entity != null) {
                            try {
                                is = entity.getContent();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int length;
                            try {
                                while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                    stringBuilder.append(new String(buffer, 0, length));
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

by the way the buffered reading is the best solution you can choose, but I dont really think thats your problem, as I have noticed before the HTTPEntity **must not be null**, so I assume there is something wrong with the HTTPRequest, maybe try to check the request-results using fiddler.

Comment: Well, I tried this before the Log.i("GET RESPONSE", response). I am still trying to put it anywhere else now.

Comment: OK, the if(resEntityGet != null) looks still null. The following instructions are not applying. Sigh, since the URL works well on my computer browser and is returning the string I need.

Comment: ok,... thats strange the entity should'nt me null (or the response is getting consumed anywhere else before but your code doesn't look as this is happening), I might take a look at it tomorrow

Comment: Thank you. By the way, as I writed in the other answer's comment, I realized that I was trying that in an activity. Should it be in the AsyncTask calling this activity ?

Comment: Yeah AsyncTask would be better, but I don't think that's causing the failure

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually use (post instead of your get but should be the same).

```
public String getMessage(){
InputStream is = null;      
String result = "";
    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(<url>);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var1", var1));   

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    Log.i("result string", result);

    }
}
```

Comment: I commented the 3 lines before that one:     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);     and it is there that the exception is caugh. Getting nervous. :S     Edit: by the way, should it not be working if it is not executed in an AsyncTask ? I just realized that I tried into an activity...

Comment: Can you post what the exception message is? Also you don't need to use AsyncTask in every situation. You can start getMessage() in a Thread and process the result in a Handler. If you need code for this send me a message and I'll update the code here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we are using in our apps, very useful in getting JSON strings

```
    String response = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClientpost = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String postURL = "http://somepostaddress.com";
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postName1", "value1"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postName2", "value2"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("postName3", "value3"));
        //And So On

        UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params);
        post.setEntity(ent);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpResponse responsePOST = httpClientpost.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();

        //Server Response
        response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd image that you're calling this from the UI thread, and Android is throwing an exception saying you can't do network I/O on the main thread. You're probably not seeing this as your catch block ignores the exception and `e.printStrackTrace()` will not dump the exception to logcat (you have to call `Log.e("tag", "boom", e);` to actually see it in the log.

Start by confirming that you're hitting the exception (fix the logging, and/or rethrow the exception), and if it is that, then you'll need to call this from another thread, e.g. by moving into an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to do it in an Activity instead of an AnsyncTask. Works better now in the doInBackground.

Thank you all.