# accessing JSON files, AsyncTask error

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

there is a `JSON` output:

```
{"status":"error","data":null,"message":"required parameters not available."}
```

To access this there is a **JSON Parsing** java class and a **User Function** java class.

I am having confusion on accessing this `JSON` file on my LoginActivity inside my AsyncTask. The task throws a **Null Pointer** exception. I really do think that not referring to the "status" is causing this ... but is that the real reason why ?? I am new to android so I have no good idea. Please do help. The code are as follows:

**JSONParser.java**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    static int GET = '1';
    static int POST ='2';

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params, int method) throws URISyntaxException {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        HttpEntity httpentity = null;

        try {
            switch (method) {
            case 1: 
                if(params!=null){
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;   
                }

                Log.e("URL", url);
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();          

                break;
            case 2: 
                HttpPost postrequest = new HttpPost(url);
                postrequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(postrequest);
                httpentity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                break;
            }

            is = httpentity.getContent();


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

**UserFunction.java**

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;
    private static String url_login = "http://10.0.0.2/blamethestars2/public/api/user/login";

    static int GET = '1';
    static int POST ='2';

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    public JSONObject login(String username, String password){
        JSONObject json = null;

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        try {
            json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url_login, params, POST);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;

    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

    EditText username, password;
    String user, pass;
    Button submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_in);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_password);


        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.user_submit);


        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                user = username.getText().toString();
                pass = password.getText().toString();
                if(user.length()<1 || pass.length()<1){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fill user name and pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    new Asynconnection().execute();
               }
            }
        });
    }   

    public class Asynconnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        JSONObject jsarray;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            UserFunctions users = new UserFunctions();
            jsarray = users.login(user, pass);      

            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

*For now I am just trying to check if the api response appears on the logcat or not*

**Logcat error:**

```
04-18 16:07:01.190: W/System.err(874): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 16:07:01.260: W/System.err(874):  at com.example.btshome.library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:66)
04-18 16:07:01.260: W/System.err(874):  at com.example.btshome.library.UserFunctions.login(UserFunctions.java:38)
04-18 16:07:01.270: W/System.err(874):  at com.example.btshome.LoginActivity$Asynconnection.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:54)
04-18 16:07:01.270: W/System.err(874):  at com.example.btshome.LoginActivity$Asynconnection.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
04-18 16:07:01.280: W/System.err(874):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-18 16:07:01.280: W/System.err(874):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-18 16:07:01.280: W/System.err(874):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-18 16:07:01.293: W/System.err(874):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-18 16:07:01.293: W/System.err(874):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-18 16:07:01.300: W/System.err(874):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-18 16:07:01.320: W/System.err(874):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: check the line where the NPE occurs

Comment: post your logcat error

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace, let us know exactly which line you're getting the NPE on, and remove any of your code which doesn't directly refer to your problem? At the moment your question has tl;dr symptoms

Comment: @user2247689 which line is at JSONParser.java:66?

Comment: guys do check, added the logcat error

Comment: @SankarV line 66: `is = httpentity.getContent();`

Comment: `httpResponse.getEntity();` returns `null` so `httpentity.getContent();` cause `NullPointerException`

Comment: @SankarV what should I do then ??

Comment: You might want to consider using the gson parser (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Super easy!

Comment: check for response status. try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14347382/1329126